# C# Serial Communication Winform UI Freezing

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, serial-communication, ui-thread

I am working on an application where a full-duplex serial communication occurs (Read/Write). Specifically, I read 256 bytes of data from a port in every 40 ms and write back other 256 bytes.

In addition to this, I have bunch of TextBoxes in WinForm and when 256 bytes of data is received, I update each TextBox based on the received data. To be able to do that, I did the following in a WinForm class:

1. Read the data in SerialDataReceivedEventHandler method (e.g. `port.Read(readData, 0, 256)`)
2. Call UpdateUI() method (within the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler method) which updates the UI elements based on the received data. (e.g. `textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(readData[0]`)
3. After finishing the UpdateUI, write another 256 bytes of data to the port (e.g. `port.Write(writeData, 0, 256)`)

My problem is that UI keeps freezing and I cannot display every read messages on UI since I don't use any threading or async mechanism. How can I make WinForm display every message without freezing?

Comment: please show us your code that reads and manipulates the UI and we can tell you how to change it

Comment: Is the only problem with displaying the information on the UI or does the application stop working too?

Comment: @PaulF I was able to read every message, applicaton does not stop working, only UI freezes.

Comment: How do you call UpdateUI? You should .Invoke it from the received event handler.

Comment: This is a firehose bug, common issue with data supplied by a threadpool thread.  The main thread needs more time to update and repaint the text boxes than the time needed to receive the data.  Inevitably, the main thread starts burning 100% core, trying to keep up, visible by repaints not occurring and the UI getting unresponsive to mouse and keyboard.  It is wasted effort, the human eye can't keep up either.  Instead, have the receiver update a field of the form class.  Use a timer to update the boxes, 100 msec is plenty good enough.  The *lock* keyword to keep it thread-safe.